# Include man pages in ubuntu docker image?

Tags: docker, manpage

https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/issues/122

```
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    dpkg -l | grep ^ii | cut -d' ' -f3 | xargs apt-get install -y --reinstall
```

I use the above command to install manpages in an ubuntu docker image.

But I got this error. Does anybody know how to fix the problem? Thanks.

```
...
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/bin/w.procps because link group w is broken
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
E: Could not configure 'libc6:amd64'. 
E: Could not perform immediate configuration on 'libgcc-s1:amd64'. Please see man 5 apt.conf under APT::Immediate-Configure for details. (2)
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -y update &&     dpkg -l | grep ^ii | cut -d' ' -f3 | xargs apt-get install -y --reinstall' returned a non-zero code: 123
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be just with reinstalling the libgcc-s1:amd64 package. I found I could 'skip' that one and everything works okay.

Here is the modified RUN line that I use

```
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    dpkg -l | grep ^ii | cut -d' ' -f3 | grep -v '^libgcc-s1:amd64$' | xargs apt-get install -y --reinstall
```